# Example of mathematical antilogies involving the equality symbol ( always false statements, for all permissible values of the variables).

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Logicians ( in propositional calculus)  classify statements/formulas  into 3 categories : tautologies ( always true) , contingent statements ( sometimes true, sometimes false) , antilogies ( always false).

I can find examples of mathematical "tautologies" , like (a+b)²=a²+b²+2ab.

I can find an example of mathematical contingent statement: a+a=a ( which is true if x=0, false otherwise), or a²=a ( true iff  x=0, x=1)

But I cannot find an example of mathematical "antilogy" ( a statement that would be false for all permissible values of the variables) that would be an equality.

Comment: How about $1=2$?

Comment: @DMcMor. I'm looking for formulas involving  at least one variable.

Comment: Then how about $a=a+1$, Eleonore?

Comment: Every arithmetical *identity*, like e.g. $(x-1)(x+1)=x^2-1$ holds for every value of $x$.

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson. Thanks!

Comment: Every arithmetical formula of the form $x=n$, where $n$ is a numeral whatever ($1,2,\ldots$) holds for some (exactly one) value of $x$.

Comment: Every arithmetical formula of the form $x=x+n$, where n  is a numeral whatever holds for no value of $x$.

Comment: Or $x>x$, or $x \cdot \tfrac{1}{x} = 0$.

Comment: @ Timon Knigge.- Thanks. I like the "x. 1/x =0" example.

Comment: x = x + 1......

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames The $x \times \frac 1x = 0$ is actually not a good example since for $x = 0$ it can't be called false, as it is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this was received well in the comments, and since it's generally considered better to have answers posted as answers: $$a=a+1$$

Digression: Of course, a lot depends on the phrase, "permissible values of the variables". If only natural numbers are permissible values, then $a+1=0$ answers the question. If only integers are permissible, $a+a=1$. If only rationals are permissible, $a^2=2$. If only reals, $a^2+1=0$. One might even object that $a=a+1$ is not an antilogy, if infinite cardinals are permissible. So perhaps one has to go to $a-a=1$ for an example of a one-variable equation that is an antilogy in any theory in which subtraction is a binary operation and $0\ne1$.